# Custom prover tactics in Idris

Tags: theorem-proving, idris

If I understand it correctly (mainly from existence of the `applyTactic` function), it is possible to write custom tactics for the theorem prover in Idris. What (or where) are some examples I could use for learning how to do that?

Comment: I don't know anything about how to write it and use, but I've seen recently [an example of custom tactic](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/base/Data/Vect.idr#L18-L22) and [an example of it's usage](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/base/Data/HVect.idr#L57). Hope this will help.

Comment: The above links are no longer valid because they refer to the HEAD of the repo. Please see here instead: [first](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/10ef56b8c1629347ab213e97bfff551ee27e11d0/libs/base/Data/Vect.idr#L18-L22), [second](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/fb6a0ed1ad5e3acc3795d7ab674977bdb419129a/libs/base/Data/HVect.idr#L57)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two mechanisms for writing custom tactics in Idris: high-level and low-level reflection.

Using high-level reflection, you write a function that runs on syntax rather than on evaluated data - it won't reduce its argument. These functions return a new tactic, defined using the pre-existing tactics in Idris. If you want to return a proof term directly, you can always just use `Exact`. An example of this kind of reflection can be found in [the effects library](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/b283c0d5a3b2d7794ddf8450b12b1a8cfe08b4e6/libs/effects/Effects.idr#L103-L149). High-level reflection tactics are invoked using `byReflection` in proof mode.

In low-level reflection, you work directly with quoted terms from Idris's core type theory. A tactic is then a function in `TT -> List (TTName, TT) -> Tactic` where the first argument is the goal type, the second is the local proof context, and the return result is the same as in high-level reflection. This is what laughadelic linked to [above](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/base/Data/Vect.idr#L18-L22). These are invoked using `applyTactic` in proof mode.